# How to convert boolean to localized string

Tags: c#, .net, string, localization, cultureinfo

There is any way to convert a boolean value to a localized string. I have tried:

```
var x = true;

var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US")
x.ToString(culture) // returns True

culture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR")
x.ToString(culture) // returns True, expected Verdadeiro
```

Or should I start typing the switch now to end before 2020?

Comment: Thats for converting from string to boolean, I want the other direction.

Comment: Start typing, because it is for a reason that you must install a language pack in Windows before you can actually 'see' the other language.

Comment: well, there is NumberFormat and Calendars for a lot of languages, why not Boolean string...

Comment: If you don't want to type it all out then `x ? "1" : "0"` is the simplest solution you've got, which would be the most universal you can get I guess.

Comment: _Or should I start typing the switch now to end before 2020?_ Did you finish the switch? tic tac. 2020 is here :)

Comment: @daniherrera Damn, need to find a way to use the lock down as an excuse to not delivering this at the next sprint...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, start typing because it's documented behaviour :)

**Boolean.ToString(IFormatProvider)**

> Remarks
>
> The provider parameter is reserved. It does not participate in the
>   execution of this method. This means that the
>   Boolean.ToString(IFormatProvider) method, unlike most methods with a
>   provider parameter, does not reflect culture-specific settings.

Answer (score 0):

As @Michal pointed out, this is the documented behavior.

If your system supports many languages, you must have some sort of [i18](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) support. Use that to convert a boolean value to string. You can add an extension method like so:

```
public string ToLocalizedString(this bool b)
{
    return ...i18n version of true or false...
}
```

Comment: If you're going to write a code sample, you should make sure that it compiles and doesn't contain pseudo code.